# Get Chrome to open Google Cloud Storage links

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, url-scheme

I would like to be able to open a tab in Chrome and enter something like `gs://bucket-name/path/to/file` and have it open the corresponding page in the GCP Web Console `https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/bucket-name/path/to/file`. I saw there are [external protocol handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome) in Chrome, but I don't want to open an external application. I just want it to open another page based on the URI. I also don't want to put up any of my own servers for this simple purpose. Perhaps a Chrome Extension that can do some simple JS on the URI after I enter it into the address bar?

Comment: The omnibox API might be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/omnibox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension : Custom Protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836554/chrome-extension-custom-protocol)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible now with link you gave (works for me).

@shiv turned my attention on fact that this is question about automated link replacement under the hood in address bar when you write "gs://bucket-...". So such handler just collects address and modifies it and uses modified version to go further.

Well then looks like you need something like this [Set custom protocol handler in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729686/set-custom-protocol-handler-in-firefox) (in case of Firefox) but unfortunately I cannot help more.

Comment: I think the question asks for a way for like an auto-redirection. For eg, you type the `gs://bucket-name/path/to/file` link, and get redirected to `console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser...` on the fly.